# How to update certain column in a table based on duplication of other columns?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

```
UPDATE tb1 SET percentage = 80 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ip FROM tb1 WHERE tb1.ip IN (SELECT ip FROM tb2))
```

The above Mysql query is written to update percentage  based on duplication of ip columns into tb1 and tb2. But it doesn't work. Mysql says that I cant make tb1 as target! How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` of both should work.

Try below :

```
  UPDATE tb1 join tb2 on tb1.ip=tb2.ip  SET tb1.percentage = 80
```